# Data point colours changing radially from a pre specified point

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, astronomy

I am wanting to set the colours of certain data points to be centred around a certain point, e.g., [1,2] on my graph, so the further away the data points are from a central point they begin to change colour. So there is some radius from this point where data points within are one colour, and so on.

I would specifically like to create a heat map with the follow hex colour codes:

FF0088, FF0099, FF00AA and 660088, 660099, 6600AA

I would also like to have the distinct colour change either side of a demarcation line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_dC = [
        [1.29940,-0.06908,0.85295,-0.32388,0.51436,0.00408,-0.83824,-0.11374,0.04466],
        [0.93471,0.10030,1.25981,-0.11888,1.35810,-0.12869,-1.47697,0.02932,0.07098],
        [0.57901,0.25031,1.77954,-0.34448,0.94303,-0.20675,-1.28751,0.23731,0.01300],
        [0.51240,0.53625,3.43752,-0.21142,0.83936,0.19316,-1.05078,0.29039,0.24586],
        [0.23750,0.81001,6.45671,-0.21533,0.50952,-0.09047,-0.72484,0.62434,0.18567],
        [0.68737,0.38333,2.41730,-0.32624,0.87260,-0.00159,-1.19884,0.16281,0.22052],
        [0.61870,0.16834,1.47348,-0.18783,0.55844,0.33093,-0.74627,0.20852,-0.04018],
        [2.05987,-0.36247,0.43404,-0.21760,0.95765,0.04392,-1.17525,-0.31384,-0.04863],
        [0.32613,0.18240,1.52197,-0.30043,1.00514,-0.00491,-1.30558,0.48662,-0.30421],
        [0.90927,-0.16005,0.69175,-0.26315,1.19294,-0.02365,-1.45609,0.04131,-0.20136],

def log_OIII_OII_OI(log_OI_Ha, eps=0):
    return ((-1.701)*(log_OI_Ha))-2.163

OI2 = np.linspace(-2.50000, 0.00000)

data_dC = np.array(data_dC)

log_OIHa_dC    = data_dC[:, 6]
log_OIIIOII_dC = data_dC[:, 7]

base_point = (-1.4, -0.8)

def boundary_x(x):
    return ((-1.701)*(x))-2.163

def myDistance(log_OIHa_dC, log_OIIIOII_dC, base):
return np.sqrt((log_OIHa_dC - base[0])**2 + (log_OIIIOII_dC - base[1])**2)

dist = myDistance(log_OIHa_dC, log_OIIIOII_dC, base_point)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(OI2, log_OIII_OII_OI(OI2), '-k')
ax.set_yticks([-1.5,-1.0,-0.5,0.0,0.5])
ax.set_xlim(-2.5, 0.0)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.0)

ax.plot(base_point[0], base_point[1], 'ko')
ax.scatter(log_OIHa_dC[log_OIHa_dC >= boundary_x(x)], log_OIIIOII_dC[log_OIHa_dC >=       boundary_x(x)], c=dist[log_OIHa_dC >= boundary_x(x)], cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
ax.scatter(log_OIHa_dC[log_OIHa_dC < boundary_x(x)], log_OIIIOII_dC[log_OIHa_dC < boundary_x(x)], c=dist[log_OIHa_dC < boundary_x(x)], cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
```

So essentially to the upper right of this demarcation line I would like the hex colours 660088, 660099, 6600AA and to the lower left of it I would like FF0088, FF0099, FF00AA.

The point to the lower left of the demarcation line is [-1.4,-0.8] and the point to the upper right of the demarcation line is [-0.9,0.2].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ax.scatter` and feed it colors based on the distance from your point. You can also use numpy's fancy indexing to select things based on criteria (like your demarcation line).

You don't include any example images of what you'd like to see, so here's a basic example of these concepts put together:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)
%matplotlib inline

def myBoundary(x, y0=0, slope=1):
    return y0 + x * slope

def myDistance(x, y, base_x, base_y):
    return np.sqrt((x - base_x)**2 + (y - base_y)**2)

x = np.random.normal(size=137)
y = np.random.normal(size=137)

y_boundary = myBoundary(x)

base_x, base_y = (-1.4, -0.8)

dist = myDistance(x, y, base_x, base_y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x[y >= y_boundary], y[y >= y_boundary], c=dist[y >= y_boundary], cmap=plt.cm.Blues_r)
ax.scatter(x[y < y_boundary], y[y < y_boundary], c=dist[y < y_boundary], cmap=plt.cm.Reds_r)
ax.plot(x, y_boundary, linestyle='-', linewidth=2, marker=None, color='k', alpha=0.65) 
ax.plot(base_x, base_y, 'g*', alpha=0.65, markersize=10)
```

And that dumps out:

[image: fancy scatter plot]

Comment: Hi Paul. This is a good start. But I have two data points either side of the demarcation line...

Comment: @MichaelRoberts that's fine. You can add as many logical statements to fancy indexes as you want.

Comment: Ideal. I'm working on this from your guidance. Thank you very much

Comment: One quick question, how would I set boundary_x to equal the demarcation line I defined in the question?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts write a function that defines that line, and the for a given `x`, evaluate that function and check if the return value is greater than or less than your `y`-data. If fill out your example code to be a little more runnable, I'll be happy to take this a litte further. Be sure leave out the nasty implementation details (e.g., what the heck is `log_OIII_OII_OI`? it doesn't matter, just substitute in a simple function).

Comment: Ok, what I have done is added my full code. It should be runable. I'm afraid the complication comes from other parts of the code which are omitted that contain other demarcation lines (this plot is part of a larger gridspec plot).

Comment: @MichaelRoberts I've added a sloping boundary to my simple example. The base point is the green star.

Comment: Hi Paul, for some reason, working with your template leaves my plot a bit strange. I don't receive errors, which is good at this stage. But both sides of the demarcation line are the same colour. I have used the def line of your piece with the second line i.e., ((-1.701)*(x))-2.163

Comment: If I do `y_boundary = myBoundary(x, y0=2.163, slope=-1.7)` everything looks fine. Is that what you're doing? (@MichaelRoberts)

Comment: Working perfect, thanks Paul. Should I now update with this as an answer?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts: no. you've already marked this response as the answer. that suffices for the stackexchange question-answer format